# Which one is most preferable @font-face or Web-font?

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

If I want to show same font in all browser, including old browsers (example: IE6, Opera9 etc.)
which one should I choose  `@font-face` or `Web-font` or both? Also I want to know Which One loads faster?

Comment: Have you looked into these guys? http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface

Comment: I would be curious to know the difference in download speed. My understanding had been that Web-fonts downloaded faster then @font-face, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @AndrewBacon No I haven't, But I will

Comment: @bassplayer7 Same Question here, which one loads faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Web-font` is just a tool designed to make `@font-face` usage easier.

I'd say just use `@font-face`. The less external resources you have (such as web-fonts), the less you have to worry about going wrong.

Comment: Does @font-face take time less time then Web-font??

Comment: Kind of, yes, because you don't have extra resources and stuff to download. It's kind of similar to how JavaScript takes less time than jQuery.

Comment: Thanks, for removing my confusion

Comment: But, I had found there is lots of complication for supporting browsers using '@font-face'. What if I don't find any other formats of the font?

Comment: There are rendering issues with web fonts, especially in Chrome.

Comment: Head on over to Font Squirrel, choose a font, and download a Webfont Kit from the font page (not a list page - click through to the font) This includes a demo HTML file and a stylesheet, so you can see how it all works.

Font Squirrel include 5 filetypes, so your devices and desktops and IE are covered.  Nice.